# running python script java jar spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that I have created using eclipse. Under the `src/main/resources`, I created a `scripts` folder and have put a simple python script that is invoked by java and output collected and dumped in rest response.

When I run the application using eclipse, the script `src/main/resources/scripts/my_name.py` runs when spring rest handler invokves it. The script is very simple and just prints a string on bash which is collected by java and sent in the rest response.

When I create a jar using run as and target as build, the jar gets created. When I run the jar from under directory where jar is created and run it from the root of the project as `java -jar ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` it works.

But when I say copy the same jar to `/tmp/mydemo` and run it, the python script is either not running or sth but the string is never shown. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Please add the code that is executing the script.

Comment: thanks. Right after posting I got a clue to the problem. I can add that code but I can pin point the issue. Maybe you will know the ans right away. The code was exeucint the script by giving the path as "src/main/java/resources/scripts/my_name.py" When I copy the generated jar to any other dir and create the same hierarchy for the script, it works. So the point I understand is that say I change the path to sth simple as "scripts/my_name.py". The challenge now left is that the dir where the jar is placed, a dir by the name of "scripts" has to be created there and my_name under it.

Comment: I was wondering that if I can just somehow make sure that since the jar file has the script the script can be executed from there or not?

Comment: I doubt that, as python cannot read the script when it is in a jar (I guess). Maybe that is more of a python question.